# How to remove rows with more then x Null values in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, null

I am having some trouble removing rows with more then the na_threshold of nulls in my dataframe

```
na_threshold=2

df3=df3.dropna(thresh=len(df3.columns) - na_threshold)
```

When I run

```
df_null = df3.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (f.col(x).isNull() for x in df3.columns)))
```

df_null is a dataframe entry with 1 row which only has one column with a null value

I have tried increasing the value na_threshold but it hasn't made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realised that the drop.na function does work

What happened is that the file was initially read in with Pandas and I had put the drop na function before converting other Null like values to Null as Pandas uses nan, NaT and sometimes "-"

````
for column in columns:
  df3 = df3.withColumn(column,when((col(column)=='nan'),None).otherwise(F.col(column)))    
  df3 = df3.withColumn(column,when((col(column)=='NaT'),None).otherwise(F.col(column))) 
  df3 = df3.withColumn(column,when((col(column)=='-'),None).otherwise(F.col(column)))
na_threshold=2

df3=df3.dropna(thresh=len(df3.columns) - na_threshold)```
````